# A linear algorithm for this specification?

Tags: algorithm

This is my question I have got somewhere.

**Given a list of numbers in random order write a linear time algorithm to find the th smallest number in the list. Explain why your algorithm is linear.**

I have searched almost half the web and what I got to know is a linear-time algorithm is whose time complexity must be O(n). (I may be wrong somewhere)
We can solve the above question by different algorithms eg.

1. Sort the array and select k-1 element [O(n log n)]
2. Using min-heap [O(n + klog n)]
   etc.

Now the problem is I couldn't find any algorithm which has O(n) time complexity and satisfies that algorithm is linear.
What can be the solution for this problem?

Comment: This have nothing to do with C++.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians

Comment: @Welgriv I'll implement it in c++

Comment: Walk the list k times and remove/return the smallest element each time. This is O(kn) and thus linear.

Comment: @VishwasLuhana I'm sorry but its not relevant. You don't show any code and you can implement an *algorithm* in almost any language you want. C++, Python, Java, C ...

Comment: @Botje Technically, if k is part of the input and given as a sequence of digits or bits, then a complexity proportional to kn is actually exponential!

Comment: @Stef don't you mean quadratic?

Comment: Note that theoretically, you get a O(n) algorithm with hashing, i.e. using `std::unordered_map`. In practice, it is likely to be slower than simply sorting the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linear search remembering `k` smallest values is `O(n*k)` but if `k` is considered constant then its `O(n)` time.

However if `k` is not considered as constant then Using histogram leads to `O(n+m.log(m))` time and `O(m)` space complexity where `m` is number of possible distinct values/range in your input data. The algo is like this:

1. create histogram counters for each possible value and set it to zero `O(m)`
2. process all data and count the values `O(m)`
3. sort the histogram `O(m.log(m))`
4. pick k-th element from histogram `O(1)`

in case we are talking about unsigned integers from `0` to `m-1` then histogram is computed like this:

```
int data[n]={your data},cnt[m],i;
for (i=0;i<m;i++) cnt[i]=0;
for (i=0;i<n;i++) cnt[data[i]]++;
```

However if your input data values does not comply above condition you need to change the range by interpolation or hashing. However if `m` is huge (or contains huge gaps) is this a no go as such histogram is either using buckets (which is not usable for your problem) or need list of values which lead to no longer linear complexity.

So when put all this together is your problem solvable with linear complexity when:

```
n >= m.log(m)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)

From cppreference:

> Notes
> The algorithm used is typically [introselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect) although other [selection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) with suitable average-case complexity are allowed.

> Given a *list* of numbers

although it is not compatible with `std::list`, only `std::vector`, `std::deque` and `std::array`, as it requires [*RandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

Comment: In a homework context, with the need to describe the algorithm, the quickselect algorithm might be enough, as it has a linear complexity in *average*. But in practice, this function is indeed the easy way to follow.